# Statistical analysis of compositional data - what test to use?

Tags: compositional-data, dirichlet-regression

For one of my studies, I am playing with what seems to be a compositional data.

In short, I have some signal that I decompose in 4 frequency bands (**B1** to **B4**) in a way that I get the relative contribution of each frequency band (in percentage). Thus, the sum of the 4 frequency bands is equal to 100%

I do that for 4 conditions (**C1** to **C4**).

Thus, I have 4 bands * 4 conditions * 20 participants = 320 entry ( *C1B1_P1, C1B2_P1, C1B3_P1, C1B4_P1, C2B1_P1, C2B2_P1, etc.*).

I would like to perform statistical analysis. I understand that due to the compositional characteristics of my data, traditional ANOVAs should not be uses.

I did some research online and found some information about the Dirichlet Regression, but I have a hard time understanding if it applies to this design. I did play with R and DirichReg and got some results, but again, since I did not understand what I was doing, I do not know if the results indeed provided information about my data... In my test, I used **C1** as the reference level and compared it to **C2:C4**. Am I going the wrong way ?

Any help in understanding what I'm doing would be much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: What is your research question?

Comment: In short, we are doing a biofeedback experiment on some kinematics parameters. We are looking at the effect of biofeedback intensity on the forearm displacement. Thus, C1 = NoFB, C2 = Feedback intensity X1, C3 = X5 and C4 = X10. The frequency bands are obtained through an analysis of the forearm displacement in a specific axis.